# Carrierwave recreate version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm using carrierwave and rmagick to handle my image uploads. I now added a new version (smallthumb) to my image_uploader.eb:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/images"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [250, 250]
  end

  version :smallthumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [70, 70]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

I have a model called "image" with the image uploader mounted:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :description, :name, :size, :image, :article_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I have read that I need to call recreate_versions!, but I do not understand where I need to call this operation and how. I have my images on the live server in public/uploads/images. How can I recreate the versions of all these images (on my development machine and the live server) so that I have the smallthumb version of the image too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `user model` has an `image uploader`.

then try this

`user.all.each {|x|x.image.recreate_versions!}`

OR

`User.all.each do |user|
  user.avatar.recreate_versions!
end`

Comment: Ok, I have a model called image (I edited the quetion and added this model). So I can add Image.all.each {|x|x.image.recreate_version!}, but where? I mean how is this code to be executed?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I wrote a after_save callback, after I had done the job once I deleted it. Maybe not the most elegant, but it worked!

Comment: You can even put this in the index action (def index) in the controller, e.g.   Image.all.each { |i| i.image.recreate_versions! }

Comment: I'd use the code Amar proposes, but I would run this as a rake task instead. That way, you can run it when necessary without having to edit it into and out of your controller methods. Here's a screencast from Ryan Bates about how rake tasks work and how to write and run them: http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

Comment: Small typo, it should be: `p.image.recreate_versions!` you're missing the 's'

Answer (score 6):

```
Image.all.each { |i| i.image.recreate_versions! }
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions

```
Image.find_each do |image|
  image.image.recreate_versions! if image.image?
end
```